If $\alpha,\beta>1,$ then $\alpha^i$ and $\beta^j$ move apart as $i,j$ increase.

Proposition: If $\alpha>\beta>1$ are real, and $\ \nexists\
 m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that ${\alpha}^m={\beta}^n,$ then there are infinitely many $m$ with
$\inf\left\{ \left\lvert \alpha^m-\beta^n\right\rvert:\ n\in\mathbb{N} \right\} =\inf\left\{ \left\lvert \alpha^k-\beta^n\right\rvert:\
 k\geq m;\ n\in\mathbb{N} \right\}.$

Is this true? Or is there a counter-example?
I think this might have to do with the irrationality measure of $\log_{\alpha}\beta.$

Just a moment,  isn't $a_k$ decreasing straight from the definition?   I think you are aiming at something similar though. Also, the min should be an inf perhaps.

I think it is technically saying what I want it to say now, although it can surely be expressed more succinctly.

Yes... there is a statement for $\alpha$, $\beta$ natural numbers, in the sense that the differences of their powers are growing to $+\infty$ if the exponents are large ( a result perhaps of Mahler?)... For arbitrary $\alpha$, $\beta$ it could be hard... maybe assume some algebraicity?

What do you mean by algebraicity?

Oh, if the numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$ are algebraic, perhaps integral too.
